# About F measurable

Tags: probability

$X:\Omega \rightarrow R^n, \tilde{X} = \{X^{-1}(U), U \text{ is an open set in} R^n \}, H_x$ is a $\sigma$ algebra generated by $\tilde{X}$. Show that $H_x = \{X^{-1}(B); B \text{ is a Borel set} \}$.

I think it could be solved by proving $H_x \subset \{X^{-1}(B); B \text{ is a Borel set}\}$ and $\{X^{-1}(B); B \text{ is a Borel set}\} \subset H_x$. I cannot prove the second part. Any hint will help.

Thanks.

Comment: since B is a borel set it will be a countable union or intersection of open sets . So the inverse will also be countable union or intersection So it will be in sigma algebra